# Errors with algorithm and algorithmic usepackages

Tags: errors, algorithmic

I'm writing pseudocode within the algorithm and algorithmic environment but both the numbering and typesetting get completely messed up.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\vspace*{2mm}
\caption{Backtracking for TSP} \label{alg:backtracking}
\emph{TSP\_BruteForce1(R,S)}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$S$ empty}
        \State $minCost$ \gets length tour
    \Else{}
        \State $minCost \gets \infty$
        \ForEach {city $i$ in $S$}
            \State Remove $i$ from $S$ and append $i$ to $R$
            \State $minCost$ \gets $min(minCost, TSP\_BruteForce1(R,S))$
            \State Reinsert $i$ in $S$ and remove $i$ from $R$
        \EndFor
    \EndIf
    \Return {$minCost$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried adding and removing curly brackets everywhere but that doesn't do much.

Comment: Did you notice the various error messages you get upon trying to compile your code? Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: BTW, the altorithms package supports both algorithm (float) and algorithmic (pseudocode) environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing incompatible packages here - `algorithmic` (from the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)) and `algpseudocode` (from [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)). Drop the former and make some new definitions for your variables and function calls. Of course, you can change these to suit your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\func}{\textsl}
\newcommand{\algorithmicforeach}{\textbf{for each}}

\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Backtracking for TSP}
  \func{TSP\_BruteForce1}($\var{R}, \var{S}$)
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$S$ empty}
      \State $\var{minCost} \gets \text{length tour}$
    \Else
      \State $\var{minCost} \gets \infty$
      \ForEach {city $i$ in $S$}
        \State Remove $i$ from $S$ and append $i$ to $R$
        \State $\var{minCost} \gets \min(\var{minCost}, \func{TSP\_BruteForce1}(R, S))$
        \State Reinsert $i$ in $S$ and remove $i$ from $R$
      \EndFor
    \EndIf
    \State \Return \var{minCost}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```